# How to get rid of circular dependency for parent/child services?

Tags: java, spring, parent-child, circular-dependency

In a simplified way, I have a Spring app with both Parent and Child objects which both have a service: ParentService, ChildService. They are directly connected and sometimes I need information both ways.

ParentService has an autowired (injected) ChildService so it can return all Child objects for parent (it has a method for getting all child ids and then it gets the Child objects from ChildService).

ChildService has an autowired ParentService because it needs to have relevant Parent object data for different operations.

What would be the best way to get rid of this circular dependency in my @Services? I can't create constructors for the services which leads to problems like for example testing these services.

Do I just have to create a duplicated Parent object which is only meant Child object and has it's own ChildParentService (which doesn't have a ChildService method of it's own)?

Any way I look at it, it's supposedly bad design.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about the issue you are having and what you are trying to solve, exactly? If your parent -> child definition follows inheritance model in java, I don't see where you could have a circular dep ? If child needs to interact with parent it can and vice versa. So what exactly is the issue you're having? Compile time error? Race condition ?? If you have a circular dependency usually means project layout needs to change. But that does not seem to be your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Lazy annotation on one of the services, either as

```
@Lazy
@Service
class AServiceImpl{

    @Autowired
    BService bservice
}
```

or as

```
@Service
class BServiceImpl{

    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    AService aservice
}
```

Using @Lazy will lead to creating a proxy to inject it into the other bean. The injected bean will only be fully created when it’s first needed.